# Why can the exit distribution of a Brownian motion be found pretending it moves in a random straight line?

Tags: complex-analysis, brownian-motion, stochastic-analysis

Let $U$ be a domain in the plane and denote by $\mu_{x_0,U}$ the distribution of a Brownian motion starting at $x_0\in U$ by the time it hits the boundary of $U$.

Why is it that for $U=\mathbb{H}$ the upper half plane and any $x_0\in\mathbb{H}$, the exit distribution $\mu_{x_0,\mathbb{H}}$ is a Cauchy distribution on the horizontal axis (centered at the first component of $x_0$, and with scale parameter equal to the second component)? Note that the Cauchy distribution on the horizontal axis is the distribution of the intersections between the horizontal axis and random straight lines through the starting point with uniformly random angle.

Obviously this uniform angle property also holds for the exiti distribution from $U=\mathbb{D}$ the unit disk when $x_0=0$ (in this case the exit distribution is just the Hausdorff measure on the circle).

The question title was written in an attention gathering fashion though: I know this uniform-angle propery can't be true for all domains, but rather I'd like to ask what makes it true for the two special cases above and what makes it false for other domains.

EDIT: In a lame sense, the answer is "it's true for the half plane because the Cayley transform preserves BM up to time reparametrization and takes the horizontal axis to the circle and has derivative proportional to $1/(z+i)^2$, the absolute value of which is the Cauchy distribution for real $z$". This isn't very revealing to what's going on though, at least to me. I still don't have a clear picture of whether the uniform angle property maybe is true for all, e.g., convex domains if only formulated well enough (e.g. first pick a random line, then simulate a one dimensional Brownian motion hitting the boundary intersected with that line)

Comment: I think this is all related to the Huygens principle. If $T_{B(x_0,r)}$ is the exit time of the ball $B(x_0,r)$ for the Brownian motion $(W(t))_{t\geq0}$ started at $x_0$, then $W_{T_{B(x_0,r)}}$ has a uniform distribution over the circle. So, it may be used to model a random particle in the wave propagating from the point source $x_0$. Then the distribution of $$W_{T_{\mathbb{H}}}=\lim_{r\to\infty}W_{T_{B(x_0,r)}\wedge T_{\mathbb{H}}}$$ will correspond to the intensity of the wave hitting the "screen" $\partial\mathbb{H}$, hence is a Cauchy distribution.

Comment: @SangchulLee Imagine the starting point is a point in the disk near the boundary.. then this principle tells you the exit probability near the starting point is at most 3/4 but really it's converging to 1 as the starting point converges to the boundary.

Comment: You are right, what I envisioned does not correctly explain what happens to the "upper-semicircular part" of the wave. Another analogy with the Huygens principle is that $\mu_{\bullet,\mathbb{H}}$ satisfies a superposition principle: $$\mu_{x+y,\mathbb{H}}=\mu_{x,\mathbb{H}}\ast\mu_{y,\mathbb{H}}, \qquad x, y \in \mathbb{H},$$ where $\ast$ is the convolution of measures. So, the distribution of $\mu_{x,\mathbb{H}}$ must be infinitely divisible. (This alone is far from pinpointing the distribution of $\mu_{x,\mathbb{H}}$, though.)

Comment: Let me clarify what is being asked, once again. Fix a domain $\Omega$ and an $x \in \Omega$. It seems that there are two *different* processes being considered : one is to start a $2D$ Brownian motion from $x$, the other is to pick an angle from $(-\pi,\pi]$ uniformly at random and execute a Brownian motion from $x$ on that straight line. Now, these two processes will exit $\Omega$ a.s., and the question is to find , for which $\Omega$, is the exit measure(which is concentrated on $\partial \Omega$) the same for both processes, is that right? This is true for the circle and half plane.

Comment: The deleted answer mentions conformal invariance which I'm sure has a say, but the bigger connection is the probabilistic one between these two processes (the 2D Brownian motion, and the 1D Brownian motion on a uniformly chosen straight line). There is a transformation between these two that should instantly reflect in the respective Poisson kernels (which are the exit measures of the respective processes).

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer really, at first i only considered the semi-deterministic process, where you pick a direction and move deterministically in a straight line in that direction. Only when trying more complicated domains did I consider the process you mentioned. I updated the question. I can't be any more specific because i don't know what the precise statement would be